# Window 8 platform for Android SDK?

Tags: android, window

I have just change a new PC hardware come with Window 8.1. Downloading Android SDK for 64 bit window version and try to run SDK manager totally response ? Is thereone facing the same issue ?

Comment: You may get some help from [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/710462/how-to-install-android-sdk-on-windows-8)

Answer (score 0):

You should open SDK Manager in administrator privilege.

Answer (score 0):

For this i suggest you to Install JRE (Java Run Time Environment) and create Environment in My Computer setting and restart PC this will solve your issue

For Further Information follow this Link

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows